# Need to add data returned from api to List, but can only post to LiveData?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

From my fragment I call: `videoViewModel.fetchContentSections();`

From my vm I call: `public void fetchContentSections(){repository.getContent();}`

From my repo I do this:

```
apiService.getContent(request).enqueue(new Callback<Content>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Content> call, Response<Content> response) {
            List<Section> sections = response.body() != null ? response.body().getSections() : null;
            if (sections != null && !sections.isEmpty()) {
                final List<Section> sectionList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Section section : sections) {
                    sectionList.add(section);
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Content> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    });
```

Data is returned, but in this scenario the list is null.

If I substitute the if statement for: `sectionsMutableLiveList.postValue(response.body().getSections());`

...everything works fine. But I need to use a non-LiveData list so I can then write the sectionList to a file. I'm hoping to then read the list from the file and post the value to a LiveData list to my vm.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To receive a result in a synchronous way from Retrofit you must use "execute".

```
   /**
   * Synchronously send the request and return its response.
   *
   * @throws IOException if a problem occurred talking to the server.
   * @throws RuntimeException (and subclasses) if an unexpected error occurs creating the request or
   *     decoding the response.
   */
  Response<T> execute() throws IOException;
```

This allows you to return the result and write it to the file. So something like this:

```
try {
   Response<Content> response = apiService.getContent(request).execute();
   List<Section> sections = response.body() != null ? response.body().getSections() : null;
            if (sections != null && !sections.isEmpty()) {
                final List<Section> sectionList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Section section : sections) {
                    sectionList.add(section);
                }
            }
} catch(IOException) {
   Log.d(TAG, "onFailure" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

The problem is that you then execute the call on the `MainThread` and your app will freeze until the call is finished. With `enqueue` and a callback, the request is performed asynchronously and your `MainThread` is not blocked.